# Polite way to ask about paycheck

Tags: politeness, email

I am a English learner, and I want to write an email to a person from HR department.

I have worked for a company for a month, but I think I have a bank account problem (Maybe I told them wrong routing number or something).  I am supposed to get a check last month and yesterday, but I haven't gotten any.  So I want to ask about it to the HR person.  How can I write an email?  Since it's sensitive issue, I want to make it as polite as possible.  Please help me out!  If you give me an example, that would be PERFECT.

Comment: This is a very important issue, and I would expect your HR coordinator to help you even if you were not trying to be polite. Can you meet them in person? That would give you the opportunity to explain yourself and show your good attitude more clearly.

Comment: write an e-mail and submit it to lang-8.com if you are really worried about politeness -- you'll get better help than here. My personal advice is that in a situation like this, it's better to act fast than to worry too much about politeness. As long as you end with a thank you, it's fine. Not receiving a pay check is a big deal!

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't the right place for this kind of question. If you want to know if a specific phrase is polite or not, we can answer that, but we don't know enough about you or your workplace to help you write an email.

Comment: @Esoteric - I don't see how this question is any different from one asking for help with the correct way is to ask for the bill at a restaurant, or understand a bus schedule, or any other times that "speech" is beneficial.  I don't see anyone asking or offering legal advice.

Comment: @hunter - lang-8.com looks like an interesting resource, but "new sign ups are suspended".  Is there a separate portal for native speakers?

Comment: @kimchi-man there are some great suggestions here. You **definitely** need to deal with this promptly. Different workplaces have different "rules" (written or implied) on who to contact and how to communicate. In my experience a good first step is to casually bring it up speak with "anyone" in a superior position to you (hopefully there is someone you're comfortable speaking to casually) and they will have better advice than us on how to proceed.  It is not appropriate to discuss dollar amounts with anyone except HR or Payroll but other than that there is nothing impolite about your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adhere to the usual rules of politeness, of course, it's no magic.

Just keep it simple, describe the situation as you did here in a plain way. And ask, with a pretty please, of course, whether they could possibly look into that. Of course, things like thanking them in advance for looking into it etc go without saying.

In the end, being overly polite and passive can be as bad as sounding rude, so don't stress out too much over it. It's more important to get across what you actually want, professionally. Saves time and nerves.